# Grep: Throw if found and show output

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I'm struggling getting these two to work together:

1. Exit with error code 1 if `grep` finds.
2. Show either the whole output or the line where it matched.

Right now I have the first, if grep matches, it exits with 1. But how can I also display some feedback to `stdout`?

Command to fail if found: `grep -vz hello`

#### Expected behaviour:

(Makefile with `all` in)

```
< Makefile grep -<magic> all

CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -Werror
all: $(NAME)
re: fclean all
.PHONY: all clean fclean re

exit 1
```

```
< Makefile grep -<magic> nothing

exit 0
```

Thanks

Comment: if you just want to invert the exit status grep already gives you, then `! grep all < Makefile` would do. But I'm not at all sure what "Show either the whole output or the line where it matched." means. Do you mean outputting some or any of a) the whole output that grep normally gives (i.e. matching lines), or b) the whole input file, or c) just one matching line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want something like this:

```bash
! grep -q -e "$expr" <"$file" || ! cat <"$file"
```

Suppose the regular expression in `$expr` does not match anywhere in the file given by `$file`. In that case, the initial `grep -q` will exit with a non-zero exit status which will be negated by the preceding `!` to result in a final exit status of zero.  The second part of the OR list will never execute. There will be no output.

On the other hand, if the `grep -q` command matches something, this triggers the second part of the OR list, which outputs the file with `cat` and sets the exit status to non-zero by negating `cat`'s exit status of zero.

Reformulated as a negated AND list using DeMorgan's law:

```bash
! ( grep -q -e "$expr" <"$file" && cat <"$file" )
```